# Hibernate MappingException: Unknown entity on session save

Tags: java, hibernate, mappingexception

I am getting exception on save operation to postgresql database using hibernate when I call `addEventAction` method from another class.

EventDAO.java:

```
package com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.db.DrAction;

/**
 * Logic for the database operations related to the actions.
 *
 */
public class EventDAO {

   //To get the logger for class
   Logger log = Logger.getLogger("EventDAO");

    /**
     * Add dispatched event action into the database.
     * 
     * @param eventAction
     */
    public void addEventAction(DrAction eventAction) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        log.info("Connection with the database created successfuly.");

        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(eventAction); //exception here
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //To get the logger for class
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("HibernateUtil");

    static {

        log.info("Trying to create a connection with the database.");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Exception Trace:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.db.DrAction
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1094)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1439)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.core.EventDAO.addEventAction(EventDAO.java:35)
```

**UPDATE:**

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/drcore</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DrAction.java:

```
/**
 * DrAction for the dr_action table
 */
public class DrAction implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * Default serial version Id.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Auto increment drActionId.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long drActionId;
    private String drVName;
    private String drVRequestId;

    private Long vKey;

    public long getDrActionId() {
        return drActionId;
    }
    public void setDrActionId(long drActionId) {
        this.drActionId = drActionId;
    }
    public Long getvKey() {
        return vKey;
    }
    public void setvKey(Long vKey) {
        this.vKey = vKey;
    }
    public String getDrVName() {
        return drVName;
    }
    public void setDrVName(String drVName) {
        this.drVName = drVName;
    }
    public String getDrVRequestId() {
        return drVRequestId;
    }
    public void setDrVRequestId(String drVRequestId) {
        this.drVRequestId = drVRequestId;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Exception Trace 2:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.core.EventDAO.addEventAction(EventDAO.java:35)    
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
```

**UPDATE:**

Exception Trace 3:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/sessionpoint/session/sessiondr/db/DrAction.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at com.sessionpoint.session.sessiondr.core.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
```

Comment: What's the DrAction  class? Does it have all annotation or how hibernate understands it's entity?

Comment: The exception means `DrAction` isn't registered as entity in Hibernate. Post `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `DrAction` class.

Comment: can you post your DrAction class and hibernate configuration?

Comment: DrAction is the POJO class for the dr_action table. Updated my code to include all files in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@Entity` to `DrAction` class, and add `<mapping class="your.package.DrAction"/>` to `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dr_action")
public class DrAction implements java.io.Serializable {
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
...
    <session-factory>
        ....
        <mapping class="your.package.DrAction"/>
    </session-factory>
....
```

**UPDATE**

You are probably using Oracle as DB, and Oracle doesn't support auto generated ids. You'll have to specify sequence that will be used for generating ids.

Execute this in database

```
create sequence DR_ACTION_SEQ;
```

And change the id mapping to this

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="drActionIdSeq") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="drActionIdSeq",sequenceName="DR_ACTION_SEQ", allocationSize=5)
private long drActionId;
```

Note that this expects that your id column is named `dractionid`, if it is not then you'll have to add a `@Column` annotation to the field, something like this

```
@Column(name = "dr_action_id")
```

You will have to do this for every column whose name isn't the same as column in database table.

Comment: So I am having 5 classes for 5 tables. Do I need to add each class entry to   `session-factory` ?

Comment: Yes, and all of them should have `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations (`@Table` is necessary only if table name differs from entity name).

Comment: After adding a mapping to configuration file, I am getting a compile time error at `<session-factory>` tag that says - "`The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)`"."

Comment: `<mapping>` elements should be added just before closing `</session-factory>` tag.

Comment: Now I am getting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` on the same save method. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you update the question with exception stacktrace? Probably some mapping is wrong.

Comment: @MyGod , the problem may  be due to  mapping of column,you will have to map your entity attribute to table column aswell.

Comment: Posted the exception trace. Please check once.

Comment: To correct you - I am using `postgresql` and I am using auto increment for field `drActionId`. Is that code doing the same ?

Comment: @MyGod Oh, my mistake. Are you using the same settings for all of your entities?

Comment: yes the hibernate config file is same for all but all entities have different classes and different fields. Also I have different `hbm.xml` file for each entity.

Comment: @MyGod You don't need `hbm.xml` files if you are using annotations (unless you use annotations for additional configuration). If you already had everything configured in `hbm.xml` files, you shouldn't have added the annotations, but you should have `<mapping resource="your.package.<YourClass>.hbm.xml"/>` entries in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: My hbm files are auto generated by a tool and I am using them. I have added mapping resource entry now as you said. Now I am getting `MappingNotFoundException` for resource. This is probably because my `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in `src/main/resources` but my `DrAction.hbm.xml` is in `src/main/java/com/sessionpoint/session/sessiondr/db`. How to resolve the path ? Please see the updated error trace above in question.

Comment: It's important that they are in the classpath of the output folder. So, when you build the application `hibernate.cfg.xml` and all `hbm.xml` files will be somewhere in the classpath, and `hibernate.cfg.xml` references them by their path in the build folder.

Comment: yes I am using maven and it is based on convention over configuration so had difficulty in getting the right path for xml's . I managed to set the correct path with maven + hibernate. Thanks for your right directions.

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines to your `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<mapping class="xxx.yyy.DrAction"/>//provide full package name
```

and `@Entity` and `@Table` `(name="dr_action") annotation on`DrAction` class

Comment: After adding a mapping to configuration file, I am getting an error at `<session-factory>` tag that says - "`The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)`"."

Comment: @MyGod can you post your dr_action schema?because the problem arises because of column name difference between entity and table and you have not defined and mapping to this.

Comment: I was having the same problem, despite the mapping in `hibernate.cfg.xml` being correct, as well as the annotations in the classes, and nothing resolved. After researching a lot about Hibernate 5.x.x., I found that beyond these settings, you need to add the line `cfg.addAnnotatedClass ()`, in your case, `cfg.addAnnotatedClass (DrAction.class)`, below the line `configuration.configure ("hibernate.cfg.xml")`. After that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `@GeneratedValue` annotation in postgre use sequence tables. since you haven't explicitly provided a name hibernate by default looks for `hibernate_sequence` sequence table.

Either add a sequence table by name `hibernate_sequence` in postgre schema or by any other name and add the name in the annotation.